# "during the agglutination process" or "in the agglutination process"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which is the best variant between the two?

> 1. A downside of population migration is considered to be the forfeit of unique cultural aspects in the agglutination process.
> 2. A downside of population migration is considered to be the forfeit of unique cultural aspects during the agglutination process.

I have read the explanations in the Cambridge Dictionary and, as I understood, both variants are correct, but I favour the variant with “in” while my colleagues voted for the variant with “during”.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, your colleagues are right. *During* is used, when we are talking about an event, activity or experience (not simply a period of time). *In* is used in Prepositional phrases, when we are talking about a period of time.